# How to remove zero frequency for frequency plot and fix time?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I produce a frequency plot:

```
Data <- structure(list(Venue = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Conference", "Journal"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2008L, 
2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 
2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L), Frequency = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 
8L, 19L, 10L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Year, y = Frequency, fill = Venue, label = Frequency)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

I receive in the plot value with zero and the year in x axis does not seem as the data frame

How is it possible to remove zero frequency from plot (but keep from year i.e. 2012 the record in the plot) and show in x axis all years for every bar?

Comment: Use `x = as.character(Year)` instead of `x = Year`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image: ggplt]

The code to get it is:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x = as.character(Year), y = Frequency, fill = Venue, 
                 label = ifelse(Frequency > 0, Frequency, numeric(0)))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
 scale_x_discrete(name ="Year")
```